# Two Layer Neural network Tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

```
#layer 1
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 30]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))
y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, w1) + b1)

#layer 2
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30, 10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
logits = tf.matmul(y1, w2) + b2
preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Hi I'm new to tensorflow and neural network. I tried to implement a two-layer neural network for digit recognition. The code works fine when there is only one layer but after I add the second layer the accuracy dropped to 0.11xxxx. What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may initialize the weights using random_normal.

```
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 30]))
...
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([30, 10]))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. It works now but it starts with only 0.43 and after 20 epoch it reaches 0.907 which is not bad but I wonder why it's even worse than 1 layer, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I also realize that the first training loss was super high (11.8), maybe that's the reason why it starts with 0.43. I used this to calculate the loss: batch_xentropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits = logits))

Comment: I found the solution, initializing with truncated_normal fixed the problem. Thanks for showing me the right direction.